# Ошибка при загрузке данных в базу neo4j

Tags: python, django, neo4j

search_info - метод на сервере который считывает GET запрос выполняет метод search_info - в итоге получаем СПИСОК total с некоторыми данными которые я отправляю в базу данных neo4j.

```
 def search_info(request):
    data = request.GET
    search = data.get('search')
    total = collection_data.search_info(search)
    create_node(total)

    return render(request, 'graph/get_graph.html')

graph = Graph("http://127.0.0.1:7474", auth=('neo4j', '********'))

def create_node(total):
    """
    Создать узлы и связи между ними
    """
    node_article = None

    create_subjects = """MATCH (article:Article)
FOREACH(n in article.subjects|MERGE(sub:Subject { name: n}) MERGE 
(sub)-[r:Раскрыта]->(article))"""
    create_authors = """MATCH (article:Article)
FOREACH(n in article.authors|MERGE(author:Author { name: n}) MERGE 
(author)-[r:Написал]->(article))"""

    for article_info in total:
        tx = graph.begin()
        node_article = Node("Article",
                            name=article_info['name_article'],
                            date=article_info['date'],
                            subjects=article_info['subjects'],
                            authors=article_info['authors'],
                            source=article_info['source'],
                            link=article_info['link'])
        tx.create(node_article)
        tx.commit()

    graph.run(create_subjects)
    graph.run(create_authors)
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Internal Server Error: /graph/SearchInfo/

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7474): Max retries exceeded with url: /db/data/transaction (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0c822a11d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[21/Oct/2019 22:04:42] "GET /graph/SearchInfo/?search=c%2B%2B HTTP/1.1" 500 15296


urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
    object at 0x7f0c822a11d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Причем если работать отдельно с бд - то есть вне обработки запроса GET с сервера -то все хорошо грузится в базу,как только в обработчике запроса проявляется код добавления данных в базу - все летит

Кто скажет в чем проблема?

Вот весь стек ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.0
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
    volumes:
      - var/lib/neo4j/data:/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - neo4j
```

и после попытки залить данные в базу neo4j говорит

```
 2019-10-22 18:11:28.504+0000 WARN  Failed authentication attempt for    'neo4j' from 172.17.0.1
```

а этот ip - это именно адресс докера

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
```

Comment: Сервер однопоточный? Какой фреймворк используется в вебсервере? Flask? Это весь стек ошибки или что-то еще было?

Comment: Однопточный ,Использую Django, было ещё, сейчас выставлю

Comment: На самом деле выяснил что ошибка в том что я отдельно запускаю в докере образ neo4j и свое приложение

Comment: Очень неординарная ошибка... Добавьте, пожалуйста, ответ с причиной проблемы :)

Comment: я добавил docker-compose.yml. Я не уверен что он адекватно написан. И кажется что ошибка именно в связи конейнеров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что я подключался к базе neo4j которая работает внутри докера а значит и ip адрес нужно было ставить докера,а не локальный адрес Сначала узнаем адрес нужного контейнера

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_id
```

а затем по этому ip коннектимся к базе

```
graph = Graph("http://172.18.0.2:7474", auth=('neo4j', '*****'))
```